# Return my object from WCF service.

Tags: c#, wcf

I have application that host `WCF service` and I want to return this class object:

```
namespace classes
{
    [DataContract]
    public class NetworkAdapter
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        private string gatewayIpAddress;
        [DataMember]
        public string Speed { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string NetworkInterfaceType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MacAddress { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        private LivePacketDevice livePacketDevice;
        [DataMember]
        public PacketDevice PacketDevice { get { return livePacketDevice; } }

        public NetworkAdapter(LivePacketDevice packetDevice)
        {
            livePacketDevice = packetDevice;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Description;
        }

        public static NetworkAdapter[] getAll()
        {
            List<NetworkAdapter> list = new List<NetworkAdapter>();
            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation uniCast in adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (!System.Net.IPAddress.IsLoopback(uniCast.Address) && uniCast.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
                    {
                        StringBuilder gatewayIPAddresses = new StringBuilder();
                        string gatewayIPAddressesDisplay = string.Empty;
                        foreach (var address in adapter.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)
                        {
                            gatewayIPAddresses.Append(address.Address);
                            gatewayIPAddresses.Append(" ");
                        }

                        if (gatewayIPAddresses.Length > 0)
                        {
                            gatewayIPAddressesDisplay = gatewayIPAddresses.ToString().TrimEnd(' ');
                        }

                        if (!list.Any(l => l.ID == adapter.Id))
                        {
                            list.Add(new NetworkAdapter(getDevice(adapter.Id))
                            {
                                Name = adapter.Name,
                                ID = adapter.Id,
                                Description = adapter.Description,
                                IPAddress = uniCast.Address.ToString(),
                                NetworkInterfaceType = adapter.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString(),
                                Speed = adapter.Speed.ToString("#,##0"),
                                MacAddress = getMacAddress(adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()),
                                gatewayIpAddress = gatewayIPAddressesDisplay
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

            //return list.GroupBy(n => n.ID).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToArray();
            return list.ToArray();
        }

        private static LivePacketDevice getDevice(string id)
        {
            return LivePacketDevice.AllLocalMachine.First(x => x.Name.Contains(id));
        }

        private static string getMacAddress(string oldMAC)
        {
            int count = 0;
            string newMAC = oldMAC;

            for (int i = 2; i < oldMAC.Length; i += 2)
            {
                newMAC = newMAC.Insert(i + count++, ":");
            }

            return newMAC;
        }

        public string defaultGateway
        {
            get
            {
                if (gatewayIpAddress != "")
                {
                    return gatewayIpAddress;
                }

                return "n/a";
            }
        }

        private static string getIpFourthSegment(string ipAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] arr = ipAddress.Split('.');
                return arr[3];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my service:

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    NetworkAdapter[] GetAdapters();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetDate();
}

[ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]

public class service1 : IService1
{
    public NetworkAdapter[] GetAdapters()
    {
        IEnumerable<NetworkAdapter> adapters = NetworkAdapter.getAll();
        return adapters.ToArray();
    }

    public string GetDate()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

When I am try to run `GetAdapters` function got this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9599960'.
```

When try to run `GetDate` function it works fine and return simple string.
maybe I need to configure my class in other way ? I have added `[DataMember]` to each member

Comment: I advice you to split data and behaviour

Comment: Try to just return a "dummy" object. In other words, do not depend on your `getAll` method.

Comment: Why did you put `[DataMember]` on a private field (`livePacketDevice`) and `PacketDevice` is a serializable object?

Comment: A good start to debug wcf services is to add some tracing. See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: user @Alberto: no they not

Comment: @user3271698 if that object is not serializable, you cannot use it in a wcf data contract

Comment: looks like request is timing out as you try to pump tons of data over the wire.

Comment: Did you try John S advice?

Comment: John S advice not working as well

Comment: you should first of all put the `[DataContract]` in the same namespace of your service interface then remove `[DataMember]` on the private members like @Alberto mentioned. Then change your client setting to something that would allow large object to come back just in case by changing reader quotas

Answer (score 0):

`LivePacketDevice` and `PacketDevice` need to be `[DataContract]`s, while it might also work if they are just `[Serializable]`. Otherwise WCF does not know how to transfer them to the client.

Also it is advisable to only transfer objects that just hold data, not functionality, as that functionality will not be available to the client. The stub created on the client side will only contain data fields, not methods, as code is not transferred/cloned.

Comment: `[Serializable]` is not necessary for `[DataContract]`. it works perfectly without

Comment: @Franck I know. That's why I wrote they need to be `[DataContract]`. What I'm not sure about is whether they can just be `[Serializable]` *without being* `[DataContract]`. (And that's also why I commented on Rudresh's answer the way I did).